# Call function on specific dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, dropdown

I am trying to call a simple function on a specific option selection in a dropdown menu.

In this example, I want to the function to execute only when the 4th option is selected

```
<select onchange="if (this.selectedIndex = 4) mypopup();">
<option value="1">P1</option>
<option value="2">P2</option>
<option selected="selected" value="3">P3</option>
<option value="4">P4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `=` / `==` - Make sure you're using the correct [comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison).

Comment: Javascript arrays are zero-based, so you want index 3 for the fourth option, and `=` is the assignment operator, not a comparison operator, so you want `if (this.selectedIndex === 3)` (or `==` would be fine, too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple.

First you need to use `this.value` instead of `this.selectedIndex`.

Second thing is you must use `==` to test equality, instead of `=` to set a new value

```js
let mypopup = function() {
  alert("Popup")
}
```

```html
    <select onchange="if (this.value == 4) mypopup();">
      <option value="1">P1</option>
      <option value="2">P2</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="3">P3</option>
      <option value="4">P4</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: This sort of logic doesn't belong in the html. This is 2019 not 1999

Comment: using selectedIndex is fine, it was just off by one

Answer (score 1):

You need a function when the onchange event is triggered and you need to check what's option selected and than you can simply trigger your other function.

```js
function selectChange(ev){
  const value = ev.target.value;
  if(value === 3){
    myPopup(); // call your function
  }
}
```

```html
<select onchange="selectChange(event)">
<option value="1">P1</option>
<option value="2">P2</option>
<option value="3">P3</option>
<option value="4">P4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to check index as below to check the 4th option is selected .

```
<select onchange="if (this.selectedIndex == 3){ mypopup();}">
<option value="1">P1</option>
<option value="2">P2</option>
<option selected="selected" value="3">P3</option>
<option value="4">P4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to handle in your function only.

```
myPopup(e, id){

  if(id==4)
    //todo
  }
  else{
    //stop the event
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
}
```

Comment: I recommend against it, no reason a popup function needs a full event, only needed information should be passed to it and it doesn't address the issue directly, doesn't show the OP what was wrong.

Comment: Why stoping propagation, not opening the popup isn't related to stop every parents' events

Comment: Yeah true, it triggered to me now. we can achieve it by stopping the function from getting called.

**onchange="if (this.value == '3') myPopup();"**

Comment: I agree with @Arthur but I dont think this would deserve a downvot

Comment: @Andam I didn't downvot but I think this isn't related to stopPropagation.. OP just drop a function without example, args are not explained, and this is not helping in any way.

Comment: It's `onchange="if (this.value == '4') myPopup();"` or `onchange="if (this.selectedIndex == 3) myPopup();"` but not `value == 3`

Comment: @Arthur, I will try to give more explanation next time.

Comment: @Arthur I did not say that you down voted this answer, sorry if I was not clear.